# Bind Kendo Grid dataSource to viewModel of template

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am using `kendo grid` within a `scheduler template`.
`CustomerScheduleViewModel` contains a `List<CustomerScheduleParticipantsViewModel>` which I want to bind in a grid.

```
@model slViewModel.CustomerScheduleViewModel
...
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerScheduleParticipantsViewModel>() // Specify the type of the grid
        .Name("Grid")
        .BindTo(Model.MyList)
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.CustomerId);
            columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);

        })
    )

...
```

But the grid remains empty; the dataSource does not contain any elements.
Here is what the Kendo UI Plugin reveals:

```
options: Object{15} 
data: null
schema: Object{4} 
offlineStorage: null
serverSorting: true
serverPaging: true
serverFiltering: true
serverGrouping: true
serverAggregates: true
batch: false
type: "aspnetmvc-server"
transport: Object{2} 
read: Object{1} 
url: ""
prefix: "Grid-"
filter: Array[0] 
table: null
fields: Array[2] 
0: Object{5} 
encoded: true
title: "Customer Id"
headerAttributes: Object{3} 
field: "CustomerId"
filterable: Object{2} 
1: Object{5} 
select: null

data: Array[0]
```

**UPDATE**
Code snippet updated: copy paste failure
I bind it to `Model.MyList` which is of type `<CustomerScheduleParticipantsViewModel>`

Comment: What does ViewBag.Products contain? As that's the dataset you are binding the grid to.

Comment: I did not know that the ViewBag would contain my model data... In fact I did not ask myself where the data actually is beeing hold. But I certainly did not expect the ViewBag to do that.

Comment: The ViewBag only contains your data if you put your data in it.  If you did not put your grid rows into ViewBag.Products(which seems an odd name for a list of CustomerScheduleParticipantsViewModel), then that is why your grid is empty...if you bind to an empty list, you get an empty list.

Comment: @ The Dread Pirate Thanks for bearing me out in this thoughts...

Comment: I did not use ViewBag. I passed a valid list to the view wich contains a kendo scheduler that uses a template containing the grid which I want to bind to the model that I have passed to the templates "parent" view. I assume here is the problem...

Comment: Then you have to show your actual code as the code in your question is clearly binding the Grid to ViewBag.Products: ".BindTo((IEnumerable<CustomerScheduleParticipantsViewModel>)ViewBag.Products)"

Comment: We would need to see what's in `Model.MyList`

Comment: The list itself is fine - it works if I am using ajax to load the exact same list.I also checked that view holds a valid list. I still think that the issue is caused by trying to access the list from the kendo template and not the actual view itself... I